# PHP redirecting with custom headers

Tags: php

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible and I need to set headers on login.php `if $_GET['reason']` isset but can someone clarify that I can't set response code then change location?

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
header("Location: http://domain.com/login.php?reason=ipbanned");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, this is not possible. A "Location" header sets the HTTP response code to `302 Found` (or another 3xx redirect code) and you can't send two response codes at a time.

**Update:**

The correct way to do what you want is to send the forbidden header on the *redirected* page, i.e. in `login.php` if `$_GET['readon']=='ipbanned'`, not on the *redirecting* page.

Comment: If you don't specify a response code, the default is 302. This is overridden if you set one yourself.

Comment: So can I set a 403 reponse code and redirect on the same page?

Comment: No you can't. You have to do it the other way around (see update)